# Mobile application launching upon receiving an E-mail

Tags: android, notifications, arduino, email

I am trying to connect an Arduino Leonardo board to an Android application through an e-mail, the Arduino sends an e-mail containing a specific text in the body of the e-mail, through an ASP.net web interface for the Arduino. I am trying to build a Mobile application that will automatically start upon receiving the "Arduino E-mail", I sadly am not experienced enough with the Android applications coding. Could someone point me through, what event(s) should I be looking for?

Please let me know if my question is not clear enough, I can provide additional information.

Comment: I believe there is no generic e-mail functionality included in Android itself (as opposed to SMS for example). Therefore, you may have to interface to an e-mail application which provides an appropriate interface or use your own e-mail client included in your app; there certainly are libs out there to do that, and getting e-mails from a POP account isn't really hard to do anyway.